# How to display a table view implemented in another class

Tags: uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I would like to display different content in its corresponding views by using only one subclass for generating a custom table view. When the table view is being filled with data, I would like to send the whole view to a specific view and display it.

When I generate the table view on the displaying view controller there is no problem. Even I can transfer the table view from the displaying view controller to another view, but when I try to generate the table view  in another class and try to call it from the the root view controller, I only get a initialised but empty table view.

Here is the code:

tableViewGenerator.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@interface TableViewGenerator : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
- (UITableView *) getTableViewForOtherVC;
@property (nonatomic, strong) IBOutlet UITableView *spreadSheet;
@end
```

tableViewGenerator.m

```
...

- (UITableView *) getTableViewForOtherVC {
    if (!self.spreadSheet) {
        self.spreadSheet = [[UITableView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0., 0., self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height/2.5) style:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
    }
    UITableView *tableViewToBeTransfered = self.spreadSheet;
    return tableViewToBeTransfered;
}
...
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 1;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = @"Test";
    return cell;
}
```

displayingVC.m

```
#import "DisplayingVC.h"
#import "TableViewGenerator.h"

@interface CTTOVViewController ()

@end

@implementation CTTOVViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    UITableView *spreadSheet1;
    if (!spreadSheet1) {
        TableViewGenerator *tableVC = [[TableViewGenerator alloc]init];
        spreadSheet1 = [tableVC getTableViewForOtherVC];
        [self.view addSubview:spreadSheet1];
    }
}
...
@end
```

I suppose that I have done something wrong on the table filling but I can not find what.
Any hint will be highly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

You don't seem to be setting the table view's dataSource and delegate properties anywhere, so you need to have these properly set.

On a separate front, what you're trying to accomplish is probably much easier if you generate a model, instead of the UITableView itself. I recommend checking out the models provided by free Sensible TableView framework as these can save you a huge amount of time.

Comment: When I set the delegates in the the getTableViewForOtherVC method the program crushes. Any idea why?

Comment: Probably because you haven't implemented the 'numberOfSectionsInTableView:' method. What does the crash log say?

Comment: 0x10e209b:  movl   8(%edx), %edi Theread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS(Code = 2,address0x8). I have added as you suggested also the numberOFSectionsInTableView but it still crushes with the self.spreadSheet.DataSource = self.

Comment: thank you for the hint of Sensible TableView. Did you work with it?

Comment: Yes I basically use it to create core data apps for my customers (sometimes web services too but I am not so good with that). Saves me a huge amount of time vs doing the work manually.